# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout con fragments

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-fragment

Tengo este error y no he podido solucionarlo espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    //toolbar
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Sliding Tab
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabs= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this));


    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_view, R.id.tabTeks);
    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

}
```

El adaptador

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {
private List<Perros> PerrosList;

public ItemAdapter(List<Perros> PerrosList){
    this.PerrosList = PerrosList;
}
@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Perros item = PerrosList.get(position);
    holder.txtCelebName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.txtCelebMovie.setText(item.getFamousMovie());
    Picasso.with(holder.txtCelebName.getContext()).load(item.getProfilePhotoLocation()).into(holder.profileImage);
    Picasso.with(holder.txtCelebName.getContext()).load(item.getImgsex()).into(holder.imgsex);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return PerrosList.size();

}
```

El FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private String[] titles ={"OVERVIEW","PORTOFOLIO","TEAM"};
int [] icons = new int []{R.mipmap.ic_adopcion, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
private int heightIcon;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context c) {
    super(fm);
    mContext=c;
    double scale=c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    heightIcon=(int)(30*scale+0.5f);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment frag=null;
    if (position==0){
        frag = new OverviewFragment();
    } else if(position==1){
        frag= new TeamFragment();

    } else if(position==2){
        frag = new PortofolioFragment();
    }
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position", position);
    frag.setArguments(b);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return titles.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
    d.setBounds(0,0,heightIcon,heightIcon);

    ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(d);
    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(" ");
    sp.setSpan(is,0,sp.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return (sp);
}
```

Y el fragment donde quiero implementarlo

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRequestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    array = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getPerros(response));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d(TAG,error.toString());
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(array);
    return rootView;
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
}
private List<Perros> getPerros(JSONObject jsonObject){
    List<Perros> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray array= jsonObject.getJSONArray("alumnos");
        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject objeto = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Perros perro = new Perros();
            perro.setName(objeto.getString("nombre"));
            perro.setFamousMovie(objeto.getString("direccion"));
            perro.setProfilePhotoLocation(img+objeto.getString("rutaimagen"));
            perro.setImgsex(img+objeto.getString("sexo"));
            lista.add(perro);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

[image: Siempre al comenzar la emulación lo manda 2 veces después cada que paso del 3 al 2 o 1 fragment lo envia]

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta para mostrar el error completo? ¿En qué parte del código se dispara?

Comment: @Mariano ya agregue la imagen agradezco tu respuesta, siempre que comienza la emulación lo envía después cada que paso del fragment 3 al 2 o 1 lo envía siempre

Comment: Aparte de ese error tambien deberias solucionar el aviso: _I/Choreographer: Skipped 128 frames! The app may be doing too much work on its main thread._  Ojo!

Comment: Comparto mi proyecto por si alguien me hace el favor de revisarlo, gracias de antemano[http://www.mediafire.com/download/31tfxywdg3jjl43/DogMain.rar]

Answer (score 1):

Este error ocurre en:

```
mRequestQueue.add(array);
```

ésto debido a que al crearse (onCreate) el array esta vació, y es llenado después (onResponse).

---

La solución es mover mRequestQueue.add(array), aunque no estoy seguro cual es la mejor ubicación;